# replace div content with css3 onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just made a table which has 120 rows, I am going to put pages numbers on the bottom to let the user select, I want to show 15 rows in one page and when the user click the second page the rows should be replaced with new 15 rows.

```
<div class="full" >
            <table class="flat-table flat-table-2" width="70%" style="margin:auto;">
                <tr><th>numbers</th><th>address</th></tr>

                <div id="page1">

                <tr><td>3</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>5</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>

                </div>

                <div id="page2">

                <tr><td>3</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>5</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>

                </div>

                <div id="page3">

                <tr><td>3</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>5</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>

                </div>

         </table>

         <div class="footer-pop">

         <a href= "3" id="page3"class="pages">3</a>
         <a href= "2" id="page2"class="pages">2</a>
         <a href="1" id="page1"class="pages">1</a>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: i can't replace the page content

Comment: Is this static or dynamic?

Comment: There is no css3 onclick you need to use javascript for the same

Comment: Just a suggestion, you can't place the `<div>` between two `<tr>`

Comment: INVALID HTML!!! Use multiple tbody elements.

Comment: use javascript or jquery, no option css3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues. Invalid html with the div inside a table and you have multiple elements with the same id. Just use multiple tbody elements with a thead

**HTML**

```
<div class="full">
    <table class="flat-table flat-table-2" width="70%" style="margin:auto;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>numbers</th>
                <th>address</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="page1">
            <tr>
                <td>1-3</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody id="page2" class="hidden">
            <tr>
                <td>2-3</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody id="page3"  class="hidden">
            <tr>
                <td>3-3</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a href="#">test</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

             <div class="footer-pop">

         <a href= "#" data-id="page3"class="pages">3</a>
         <a href= "#" data-id="page2"class="pages">2</a>
         <a href="#" data-id="page1"class="pages">1</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(".footer-pop").on("click", "a.pages", function (evt) {
   evt.preventDefault();
   var id = "#" + $(this).data("id");
   $("table").find("tbody").addClass("hidden").filter(id).removeClass("hidden"); 
});
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden { display:none; }
```

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/tkmm0n6w/

Comment: i tried your code and when i press on the second page , i still see the first page content :(

Comment: Because you probably did not assign the link clicks in an onready handler like it is in the fiddle.

Comment: how to make toggle: clicking on page number jumps back to top of the page ?

Comment: i didn't cancel the click , please help me to make clicks jumps to top of page , BTW JS noob here:D

Comment: My code cancelled the click with `evt.preventDefault();` Did you you not copy that?

Comment: scroll down and choose the page number , it won't jump to top

Answer (score 2):

the followinig code should work when you give all divs class "pages" and there should be one page for each button.

and give

```
$('.footer-pop a').click( function(){
 var self = $(this); 
$('div.pages').hide();
$('div.pages').eq(self.index() +1 ).show()

});
```

any way i didnt tried .. please check this

Answer (score 0):

Here is I use jQuery, and edit some your HTML.

**HTML**

```
<div class="full" >
        <table class="flat-table flat-table-2" width="70%" style="margin:auto;">
            <tr><th>numbers</th><th>address</th></tr>
            <tr class="page1"><td>3</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
            <tr class="page1"><td>5</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
            <tr class="page1"><td>1</td><td><a href="#">test</a></td></tr>
            .......
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
   $('.footer-pop a').on('click', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();

       $('tr[class^="page"]').hide();
       $('tr.' + $(this).attr('data-tr')).show();
   });
});
```

[Live view example here..](http://jsfiddle.net/aldiunanto/tot4oxs2/)